# Cannot read property 'style' of undefined React Native

Tags: react-native

I removed some of unused dependencies from package.json file and then I did `rm -rf node_modules` and then `npm install`.

If I now build my project in Xcode I do not get any errors, but If I try yo run it in a simulator I get red screen as follows:

[image]

In the simulator I get :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of null
    at launchEditor (/Users/boris/Projects/autralis-seller/AutralisSeller/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/util/launchEditor.js:153:29)
    at Object.handle (/Users/boris/Projects/autralis-seller/AutralisSeller/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/middleware/openStackFrameInEditorMiddleware.js:17:7)
    at next (/Users/boris/Projects/autralis-seller/AutralisSeller/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)
    at Object.handle (/Users/boris/Projects/autralis-seller/AutralisSeller/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/middleware/getDevToolsMiddleware.js:74:7)
    at next (/Users/boris/Projects/autralis-seller/AutralisSeller/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)
    at Object.handle (/Users/boris/Projects/autralis-seller/AutralisSeller/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/middleware/getDevToolsMiddleware.js:74:7)
    at next (/Users/boris/Projects/autralis-seller/AutralisSeller/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)
    at Object.compression [as handle] (/Users/boris/Projects/autralis-seller/AutralisSeller/node_modules/compression/index.js:205:5)
    at next (/Users/boris/Projects/autralis-seller/AutralisSeller/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/boris/Projects/autralis-seller/AutralisSeller/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/middleware/loadRawBodyMiddleware.js:20:5)
```

I do not have idea what's going on. Any idea how to solve it?

**EDIT**

Scene.js is from react-native router-flux navigation:

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Pavel Aksonov
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 *
 */
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { ViewPropTypes, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class extends React.Component {

  // @todo - should all props be documented/specified here?

  static propTypes = {
    tabBarStyle: ViewPropTypes.style,
    tabBarSelectedItemStyle: ViewPropTypes.style,
    tabBarIconContainerStyle: ViewPropTypes.style,
    tabBarShadowStyle: ViewPropTypes.style,
    tabSceneStyle: ViewPropTypes.style,
    tabStyle: ViewPropTypes.style,
    tabTitleStyle: Text.propTypes.style,
    tabSelectedTitleStyle: Text.propTypes.style,
    tabTitle: PropTypes.string,
  };

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the source code of Scene.js at line 30 ?

Comment: @BrunoGrieder I updated my question. That is from `react-native router-flux` navigation

Comment: could you post the code that contains/call the scene in your project?

Answer (score 3):

So I had this issue as well and your post helped me solve it. React Native Router Flux was updated roughly 2 weeks ago, where View.propTypes was deprecated for the new ViewPropTypes. Here's the commit for it. https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/commit/36dc20418987850677c52905beda59310a0500c3

The issue is that when this update was committed to the live branch the library version was not incremented from 3.37.0 so if you have done an npm install after that commit was implemented, your package would update with the new change, but you would most likely be none the wiser to what they had done (unless you read the commit updates for every package you use in a project)

I found that reverting react-native-router-flux to an earlier version fixed this issue. I used 3.36.0

```
npm install react-native-router-flux@3.36.0 --save
```

Comment: +1 the tutorial I downloaded was using react router v3.37.0 and gave this error. I took your suggestion to peel back to v3.36.0 and it worked perfectly after that. Thx